# Shopify polaris maintain height ratio of Card in Layout

Tags: reactjs, shopify-app, polaris

I'm using shopify polaris to create my shopify app and I'm trying to use the `Layout` component along with the `Card` component to properly structure the page. So right now, I have two cards inside of a `<Layout>` but the problem is, since the two cards don't have the same amount of data in them, they are of different height (Polaris adjusts the size on its own), and it makes it look bad. Here is an example of what I'm talking about: https://codesandbox.io/s/y37on11x9j .
If you open the sandbox result on a separate browser, to see it in full screen, you'll see that there are two cards that have different heights. I just want them to be the same height. Can I get any help in doing this? Thanks!

Comment: How about applying external css?

Answer (score 0):

Add a Box element inside of the Card element and use the minHeight property: https://polaris.shopify.com/components/layout-and-structure/box

Your layout section should look something like this. If you have three of these Layout.Sections next to each other, they would all have the same height unless one extends pass the minHeight.

```
<Layout.Section variant="oneThird">
  <Card>
    <Box minHeight="460px">
      <BlockStack gap="500">
        <Text as="h2" variant="headingMd">
          Small Header
        </Text>
        <Text as="h3" variant="headingXl">
          Big Header
        </Text>
        <Text variant="bodyMd">
          Body Text
        </Text>
      </BlockStack>
    </Box>
  </Card>
</Layout.Section>
```